# routing error after updating emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i try to update my app emberjs version from 1.0.0 rc8 to 1.0.0 but i get route error . in my application Route i have these code :

```
OlapApp.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('column').set('model', OlapApp.AxisModel.find());
       this.controllerFor('row').set('model', OlapApp.AxisModel.find());
   },
   renderTemplate: function (controller, context) {
      this._super(controller, context);
      this.render('application');
      this.render('column', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'column',
        controller: 'column'
    });
    this.render('row', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'row',
        controller: 'row'
    });
},
  dimenssionTree: function () {
    return OlapApp.MeModel.find();
}
});
```

and get this error :

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of          putting them in an `actions` object (error on <OlapApp.ApplicationRoute:ember314>)
    at Object.triggerEvent (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:30519:13)
    at trigger (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29641:16)
    at handlerEnteredOrUpdated (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29537:11)
    at file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29512:9
    at eachHandler (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29559:9)
    at setupContexts (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29511:7)
    at finalizeTransition (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29835:7)
    at transitionSuccess (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:29732:13)
    at invokeCallback (file:///F:/OLAP/app/lib/ember.js:8055:19) ember.js:394
 Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember.js:394
```

if comment these line :

```
     this.controllerFor('column').set('model',OlapApp.AxisModel.find());
    this.controllerFor('row').set('model',OlapApp.AxisModel.find());
```

i can see my app but app dosent work and i think error from these tow line. i also update ember-data to last version from builds.emberjs.com

Comment: are you using ember data as well? and if yes which version?

Comment: i download ember-data from [ember data builds](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/canary/daily/20130902/ember-data.js) and using FIXTURES .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i change the

```
this.controllerFor('column').set('model',OlapApp.AxisModel.find());
```

to

```
this.controllerFor('column').set('model', this.get('store').find('AxisModel'));
```

and know i can see my app but i i dosent declear FIXTURES i get an error that say can't find any FIXTURE for AxisModel

Answer (score 5):

The error posted comes from `dimenssionTree` that should be in an `actions` object as mentioned in the error:

```
actions: {
    dimenssionTree: function () {
        return OlapApp.MeModel.find();
    }
}
```

Like you found `OlapApp.AxisModel.find()` should be written `this.store.find('AxisModel')`. As for the FIxtures might be good to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
this.controllerFor('column').set('model', this.get('store').find('AxisModel'));
```

should rather read:

```
this.controllerFor('column').set('model', this.get('store').find('axisModel'));
```

The main difference is to change `AxisModel` to `axisModel`.

You can read [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#elimination-of-modelfind-and-modelcreaterecord) more about the transition.

Hope it helps.